# Editor initialization failed site is incorrect in rcp eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

please did you find a solution!

Unable to create part

Editor id : rcp_demo.Editor.emp.

Editor initialization failed: rcp_demo.Editor.emp.  Site is incorrect.

**Package Name: RCP_Demo.Editor**

**Class Name:Emp_command.java, Emp_Editor.java, Emp_Editor_input.java**

```
public class EmpCommand extends AbstractHandler{
    public static final String Id = "rcp_demo.Editor.EmpCommand";

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

         IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
            IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
            EmployeeEditorInput input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
            try {
                page.openEditor(input,EmployeeEditor.Id);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                System.out.println("Error:" + this.getClass().getName() + ":" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new ExecutionException("Error open EmployeeEditor");
            }
        return null;
    }
}
public class EmployeeEditorInput implements IEditorInput{
//IEditorInput implements all methods 

}
public class EmployeeEditor extends EditorPart{
    public static final String Id="rcp_demo.Editor.emp";

    @Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
            throws PartInitException {
            }
    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        }
}
```

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here. Explain in more detail exactly what you are doing.

Comment: thanks bro, full describe this qeustion

Answer (score 2):

An empty `init` method is not acceptable for an `EditorPart`. The absolute minimum for `init` is:

```
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
        throws PartInitException {
    setSite(site);
    setInput(input);
}
```

You can do other things in the `init` method but you **must** call `setSite` and `setInput`. Your error is because you are not calling `setSite`.

Answer (score 0):

> Brief describe : Editor initialization failed Site is incorrect.

```
public class ProductEditor extends EditorPart {

    //initialize editor when assigned its site
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
            throws PartInitException {

        //instanceof in java is also known as type comparison operator
        if (!(input instanceof ProductEditorInput)) {
              throw new PartInitException("Invalid Input: Must be "
                      + ProductEditorInput.class.getName());
          }
          setSite(site);
          setInput(input);
    }

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    parent.setLayout(null);
    Label lblProductEditor = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    lblProductEditor.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 16, SWT.BOLD));
    lblProductEditor.setBounds(36, 45, 285, 48);
    lblProductEditor.setText("Product Editor");
    }
}
```